# Fast Process Detection

Tags: c#, process, detection

i have this piece of code to detect a Process:

```
private Boolean IsGameRunning()
    {
        Process[] game = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process process in game)
        {
            if (process.ProcessName.Contains("GameWindow"))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Since the code has to run a lot of times because it is inside a Timer, is there any way to improve the speed of the process?
I do not have any control over the game.

This code is inside a timer always enabled with an interval of 2000-3000 ms:

```
if (IsGameRunning())
            {
                Do stuff
            }
            else
            {

                Status("Waiting for game to start");
            }
```

Comment: Why not let the GameWindow process set a global boolean flag when running, and you can check whether the game is running by checking that flag?

Comment: @JohnDoe How you do that? Can you provide some sort of link or even code? thanks

Comment: What do you want to do when the `GameWindow` process stops running?

Comment: How is the process started?

Comment: @mclaassen the process is not run by my app, its a game started by Steam whenever the user wants to run it.

Comment: @Dennis just display a message

Comment: If its only running every 2 to 3 seconds then I wouldn't worry about the speed.

Comment: @mclaassen Well ok then, i just want to have clean fast code, without much usage of computer resources

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" - Knuth

Comment: By the way, you can use `Process.GetProcessesByName("GameWindow")` to make your code cleaner, but the underlying logic is similar to that of yours (still has to get a list of a processes, as it ultimately calls NtQuerySystemInformation() in Ntdll.dll). (Check it on [Reference Source](http://sourceof.net)!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the process is launched by another, in this case Steam, we can narrow the list to search to only child processes.

First, need to get the parent process id (PID).

```
var parentProcess = Process.GetProcesses().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProcessName == "Steam");
```

Then using the Windows Management Instrumentation (accessed using the `System.Management.dll`), you can then search **only the child processes**.

```
bool IsGameRunning(int parentProcess, string childExecutableName)
{
    var query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE ParentProcessId = {0} AND Name = '{1}'", parentProcess, childExecutableName);

    using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
    using (var results = searcher.Get())
    {
        return (results.Count > 0);
    }
}
```

e.g. `IsGameRunning(parentProcess.Id, "SuperMeatBoy.exe")`

**No guarantee** that this is faster as I haven't done any comparative testing, however from prior experience using the WMI is more performant than iterating a list of processes.

If you want to go further, a more advanced solution would be to hook up events to tell you process is created and deleted using a `ManagementEventWatcher` as shown in this blog post http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/438006.

Answer (score 0):

WMI gives you a visible performance hit with noticeable recurring CPU spikes when looking at it run in task manager. The way I made my process hunting work was to use a linq statement on Process.GetProcessByName, which I've never seen go above 0% when scanning for processes every .3 seconds. I store the processes I already know about in the memory, and filter them out in the linq statement.

If your EXE has enough permission (or is elevated), you can set EnableRaisingEvents = true, and attach to the Exited event to know exactly when the process dies.